# Помогите решить вопрос с телеграм ботом на telebot

Tags: python, telebot

написал часть бота и все работало но когда стал добовлять некоторые кнопки начало выдовать ошибку после нажатия на кнопку "Промокод"
Код:

```
import telebot
import config
import random
import sqlite3 as sql
from telebot import types

con = sql.connect("data.db", check_same_thread=False)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INT)")

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6755726277:AAFrUgBaMeKSyeRJeK8toQCUrk79jOT8Cns')

chan_id = -1002007922846
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    
    markupp = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Подписаться", url="https://t.me/+ld7jowsQLxwxYjA6", callback_data='subscribe')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Проверить", callback_data='check')

    markupp.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, " + message.from_user.first_name +"!"
     "\nДля использования бота - подпишись на наш канал", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markupp)
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def c_listener(call):
        
        if call.data == "check":
          x = bot.get_chat_member(chan_id, call.message.chat.id)
        if x.status == "member" or x.status == "creator" or x.status == "administrator":
            #bot.send_photo(id, open('start.jpg'))

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация", url="https://1wgtqa.life/casino/list?open=register#siml", callback_data='next')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Получить сигнал", callback_data="signal")
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Промокод", callback_data='promo')
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"""Добро пожаловать в EPLMINESBOT!

        Mines - это гэмблинг игра в букмекерской конторе 1win, которая основывается на классическом “Сапёре”.
        Ваша цель - открывать безопасные ячейки и не попадаться в ловушки.

        Шанс на победу ≈ 80%.""", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?)", (call.message.chat.id, ))
            con.commit()
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы не подписались!", reply_markup=markupp)

    @bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
    def lalala(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'promo':

                markup = types.InlineKeyboardButton(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация", url="https://1wgtqa.life/casino/list?open=register#siml", callback_data='next')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Получить сигнал", callback_data="signal")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("<<Назад", callback_data='check')
                markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' ПРОМОКОД - "EPLTAKE500"', reply_markup=markup)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
        


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка:

```
     File "c:\Users\dimon\bots\bot.py", line 68, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\dimon\bots\.venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1104, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\dimon\bots\.venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1179, in __threaded_polling  
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\dimon\bots\.venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1141, in __threaded_polling  
  File "C:\Users\dimon\bots\.venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 7868, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "c:\Users\dimon\bots\bot.py", line 31, in c_listener
    if x.status == "member" or x.status == "creator" or x.status == "administrator":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: вы обращаетесь к переменной до ее объявления.  не соблюдены отступы, по этому ваш `if x.status...` в 31 строке не понимает о каком `x` идет речь

Comment: Не зная языка уже казино пишут :)

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Обычно это как-то связано )  Не можешь зарабатывать написанием нормальных программ - пишешь казино, или что похуже ))

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Создаю не для себя а для знакомых чтобы быть в "доле")суть мне неважна, деньги - вот что важно :)

Comment: @Дмитрий это оффтоп, конечно, но молитесь, чтобы ваши знакомые не открывали исходники